# Counting correct mean in long format only once per id in R

Tags: r, group-by, counting

I'm having a difficult time understanding how to calculate a mean when the data is in long format (i.e: each observation has its own row).

For example, I have joined a database of surgeries and of transfusions (receiving blood products) based on social id and date of surgery. To this I add a column called "transfused" which is a binary switch, if the row contains any transfusion (i.e. blood,  plasma, platelets = 1, then transfused = 1)

Each surgery and each transfusion is it's own row in the data, which causes there to be many rows per id, making mean calculations incorrect.

For example, if we have a simple example with a dataset containing just 2 actual surgeries, where one of them receive 50 transfusions, and in one of them no transfusions; In the combined dataset, I'll have 51 full rows (due to R recycling).

In reality 50% of the surgeries required a transfusion, but in the above example the mean-calc will show that 50/51 surgeries were transfused.

Where am I going wrong?
I realize R is doing exactly what I'm telling it to do, but I can't figure out how I should proceed so that the "transfused" flag is only set or counted once per unique id and date in the end-calculation

```
library(tidyverse)

surgeries <- tibble(
  id     = 1:10,
  operation  = c("App", "App", "App", "App", "App", "App", "App", "App", "App", "App"),
  date   = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-05")
)

transfusions <- tibble(
  id     = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,8,8,8),
  type  = c("Blood", "Blood","Plasma","Blood","Platelets","Blood","Blood","Plasma","Blood","Blood"),
  date   = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-05")
)

combined <- surgeries %>% 
  left_join(transfusions, by = c("id", "date"))

combined <- combined %>% 
  mutate(
    transfused = if_else((type == "Blood" | type == "Plasma" | type == "Platelets"), 1, 0, missing=0)
  )

aggregate(combined, by=list(Operation = combined$operation), mean)
```

The desired outcome for the mean should be 2/10 in the above example, but becomes 3/11 because of the format of each row being an observation

Comment: n_ids <- length(unique(surgeries$id))

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that left_join creates more rows, you can fix it by summarising the results

```r
library(tidyverse)

surgeries <- tibble(
  id     = 1:10,
  operation  = c("App", "App", "App", "App", "App", "App", "App", "App", "App", "App"),
  date   = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-05")
)

transfusions <- tibble(
  id     = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,8,8,8),
  type  = c("Blood", "Blood","Plasma","Blood","Platelets","Blood","Blood","Plasma","Blood","Blood"),
  date   = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-05")
)

combined <- surgeries %>% 
  left_join(transfusions, by = c("id", "date"))

combined <- combined %>% 
  mutate(
    transfused = if_else((type == "Blood" | type == "Plasma" | type == "Platelets"), 1, 0, missing=0)
  )

combined %>% 
  group_by(id,operation) %>% 
  summarise(transfused_right = any(transfused == 1),.groups = "drop") %>%
  group_by(operation) %>% 
  summarise(mean_rate = mean(transfused_right))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   operation mean_rate
#> * <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 App             0.2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi! You're right that left join adds a bunch of rows, and I think it's part of the problem. I tried your code sample, and I do end up with an value, but I'm not sure what the value is for. Given that it's grouped by id and operation I assumed it'd print out the operation name and the mean ( I have many surgeries in the original dataset), but I end up with a singular value, with no name or title to it.

Comment: in that case just group by operation before the last summarise

Answer (score 0):

Patient `ID = 1` had one surgery and two blood transfusions, so in your final `combined` there is a duplicate row. Since you are only counting whether a patient had any transfusion (yes or no) and not the number, remove the duplicate before you do the calculation:

```
combined %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(operation) %>%
  summarize(mean_transfusions = mean(transfused))

`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  operation mean_transfusion
  <chr>                <dbl>
1 App                    0.2
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks like on the right way, but in my actual data I have many types of surgeries, when I run the distinct() command all the end table becomes nameless object with a number dbl. Not sure what it stands for. I tried adding a group_by(surgery) %>%, before, but then I get the same result as before

Comment: I created a new dataframe using distinct() on my 'main data', it still seems like there are multiple instanceso of the same 'id' in it.. because some far off column (such as the age of the blood donor for the blood pack) is distinct

Comment: The column containing the type of surgery is `operation`, right? Try `group_by(operation)`. Your sample data only had one value of operation, so I did not include that step.

Comment: Indeed in regards to operation, I've tried the revised code, manually inspecting the data still shows the id rows being duplicated many times. I think it's because the rows truly are distinct, in that for each observation of transfusion, they are unique on timestamps for example, so it's not a real 'duplicate' per se.

Comment: I removed as many unneccessary colums as possible, which finally allowed distinct() and groupby to do it's magic!

Comment: But when I manually open the dataframe, after piping the groupby to it, it still has many rows with the same id. Is the groupby a flag not seen in the dataframe manually?

Comment: @hiphopcrates - None of the operations done change the underlying data.frame. If you want a new data.frame, you need to assign the output of the pipe to a new object.